# How to always return to same activity on back button?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a main activity with a menu. The menu items lead to other activities. I am trying to implement it so that when I start a new activity from the menu, upon pressing the back button the app returns to the main activity regardless of how many other activities were previously opened.

I have tried to use the CLEAR_TOP flag but that doesn't do the trick.

```
menuItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent i = new Intent(AppMenuActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        resideMenu.closeMenu();
    });
```

Comment: Check SomeActivity in manifest

Comment: Use finishAffinity with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. It will close all activities & start only 'SomeActivity' or make your main activity with launch mode - single top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) android documentation:

> **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**
>
> ```
> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
> ```
>
> If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and
>   you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it
>   will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to
>   the current instance's onNewIntent().

What does it mean?

- If launch mode of your activity is "multiple/standard/default" **AND** you do not set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created.
- If launch mode of your activity is not "multiple/standard/default" **OR** you set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the same intent, then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's `onNewIntent()`.

Because your MainActivity has "default" launch mode and you do not set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the same intent, so it will be finished and re-created.

But you want users back to current instance of MainActivity, so you need to 
set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the same intent.

Just change your code from

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

to

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: @BenjaminBajić It is not a trick, this solution is recommend by Android, so this is official solution =))

Comment: I said it did the trick, meaning it helped me solve the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminBajić sorry I didn't get you. now I understood.